# Trying to get the MAPI ID of an Assigned Task in Outlook

Tags: mapi, exchange-server-2007, outlook-object-model

I am currently writing an application that reads tasks from a Database and creates them in Outlook.

In the database the tasks can be "Assigned" to a particular user and I have the task in outlook get assigned also.

When the task is created in Outlook it is assigned an EntryID and a task is created for the assigned user with a different EntryID

My problem is that if the task in the database get's updated I want to be able to update the Outlook Task as well as update the task for the assigned user.  My problem is that I cannot find where the MAPI ID of the child task is stored.  I have the EntryID of the Parent Task.

I am assuming that the MAPI ID of the assigned task is stored in the parent task or there is a link between the two?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two tasks in your Outlook then they have two different EntryIDs and they are not linked at all.

If you are using Extended MAPI or Outlook Object Model you can store on your Task Items UserProperties. That can hold any data you want. In this case you would like to save some sort of ID from your Database on these particular Tasks. This allows you to locate tasks that needs to be updated.

I hope I understood your question and this soultion will help you :D